# How to have both section titles centralized and with small font in the mentioned text?

Tags: sectioning

In the following TeX, how to get both section titles centralized and their fonts small. It seems I cannot have both.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\sectionfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\small}


\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[backref]{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\let\footnote=\endnote
\renewcommand\enmark[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\frenchspacing


\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}

\usepackage{setspace} 


\begin{document}
\section{Prelude}
\label{S:1}
\noindent Sometimes people simply intend toe

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Section commands are usually provided by the document class, also some packages change the layout. TeX Live contains more than 400 classes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Provided and question edited.

Comment: The only (meaningful) reason for using the `elsarticle` document class is that have to use it because you're preparing to submit a paper to an Elsevier journal. The journal editor(s) will likely not look kindly upon hacks of their software.

Comment: @Mico Then which document class to use to have all the features like \title and \keywords commands etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code snippet from the question:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\small}
```

The second `\sectionfont` overwrites the settings from the first. But, both can be merged to one command:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\small\centering}
```